# How to fix subfolders IIS7 functionality?

Tags: iis-7, web-server, domain, web-hosting

I have a problem in my sharing hosting that all websites in subfolders, their URL appear like this: http://amrelgarhy.com/amrelgarhy/

I sent to godaddy, and they sent me that its because of IIS7 and they can't solve, any one can tell me how to fix that?

Here what i sent to godaddy and their reply:

*"as i saw before on this page http://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/hosting/shared.asp?ci=9009 compare windows plans, "Multiple Web sites: unlimited" so i have the right to run more than one website inside my hosting.
But what i am facing now that i can't make more than website as a primary website.
I have igurr.com as a primary website, i want to make others as primary because:
I am facing a problem that all home pages for the other websites "which physically in sub folders" are like that "http://amrelgarhy.com/amrelgarhy/" the URL + the folder name and that what i don't want."*

**GODADDY**
*"Thank you for contacting Hosting Support. The behavior you are describing is standard for IIS 7.0 accounts. All alias domains in this environment will append the foldername their located in. I.E. a an alias domain www.coolexample.com pointed to the '/example' directory will display in a browser as "www.coolexample.com/example". This is due to the way IIS 7.0 handles virtual directories. Unfortunately we do not have any direct work around for this. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause. "*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the previous answers given to you, you need to create each site as a virtual host of its own in IIS. However the godaddy account does not seem to allow this, it only lets you have 1 primary domain, and all the other domains as subfolders of that domain. Basically godaddy are only allowing you 1 virtual host in IIS.

You need to upgrade your account to one that allows multiple virtual hosts, or change providers, to do what you want.

Comment: but they didn't say that, they said its an IIS7 problem, thats not true, right?

Comment: If you had a standard server, running  IIS 7 you could have multiple virtual hosts, each for a different site, so you could have www.site1.com and www.site2.com etc, this is a problem with godaddy restricting you to a single virtual host, so you can only create sub folders