# Does anyone using godaddy shared windows webhosting, have multiple websites on it and faced this problem?

Tags: iis-7, web-hosting, godaddy

I have multiple website on the same shared hosting on godaddy server, its Deluxe Hosting - Windows plan.
I asked before a question about this: [How to fix subfolders IIS7 functionality?](https://serverfault.com/questions/13906/how-to-fix-subfolders-iis7-functionality)
But i feel that no one is facing this problem except me, so i want to know what i am doing wrong or if someone had the same problem please tell me.

all my website are in subfolders from the root folder, the problem that all links are showing like this: www.example.com/example/...., www.anotherwebsite.com/anotherwebsite/....
such as this http://amrelgarhy.com/

Means the folder name is showing in the URL, i did all what i can and discussed with godaddy a lot, but they always tell that its a IIS7 problem.

Did you face this problem before or know a solution for?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here... try using url rewriting dude...

Comment: :), this one of the options, the second option is to go to another hosting or a dedicated server, I got a dedicated server and left all of these.